# Have mat-card a consistant size even with though it has images with different size/aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I'm making a comic book server and web app to read them and I've got a page that lists all the books in your storage using mat-card:

```css
.bookCard {
  width: 50%;
}

.coverImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.actionButtons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<mat-card class='bookCard'>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{book.title}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>@{{book.path}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <div class='coverImage'>
    <img mat-card-image src="{{book.cover}}" alt="Manga Cover Image" class='coverImage'>
  </div>
  <mat-card-actions class='actionsButtons txt-center'>
    <button mat-raised-button color='secondary' slot='end'>Edit</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color='primary'>Read</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

I am having an issue where if the book cover is not in portrait aspect ratio the vertical size of the mat-card shrinks and looks inconsistent.

I am also having an issue of responsiveness but that's another issue.

It would be great if I could have some help with the inconsistency problem.

Comment: Do you want that the image always shows completely, possibly with space at the top/bottom or at the sides, or do you want it to fill the given space, possibly with some part cropped?

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth for the reply. 

The best would be your second option with the images to show in a given space with parts of an image that don't fit being cropped.